# Android/Webpage API architecture

Tags: android, node.js, rest, architecture, hapi.js

If I have a website and an android application, it is correct to build a Rest API service to use it in both (web and app).

This way is more flexible to make changes one time right?

I'm using Hapijs and Catbox-Redis to handle the session store, also I am working on separated projects to deploy the API and Web projects on separated servers.

It is correct to use one API service for the Android Application and the Webpage?

Comment: The answer to this question lies in understanding of what RESTful API is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely appropriate.  This is one of the big advantages of a services layer.  It is very likely you will need some things that are specific to each, but most things will be common.

The really great thing will be when you have to write the THIRD interface that you don't know about yet (Google glass, apple TV, android watch, SOAP, who knows)